# how should I host my service such that other computers can consume myAppService using Internet

Tags: c#, wcf, hosting

I have created a WCF service called MyAppService.

Now, I don't want to host that service on any servers. I would like to host it in my Computer. I know how to host a WCF service in Console/Windows App, as a Windows Service and in IIS.

But I have a problem to host this service in my computer. I mean in short that I want my Computer to Work as server and other computers should be able to consume myAppService from my computer via internet.

So, I would like to ask what is the best hosting option for me and how should I host my service such that other computers can consume myAppService using Internet. 1 more question : If the above problem is solved, then can I use netTcpBinding or I have to use some HttpBinding?

Comment: Negative voters please care to comment.

Comment: I guess that the best approach will be host the services on IIS. And using HTTPBinging. But, what's the best for your consumers? If HTTP is not a problem, choose that one. It's easy to consume from other types of client, like browsers or rest request.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are looking for server configuration help (e.g. IIS) or whether you're looking for information about getting client web traffic to your computer (e.g. DNS resolution, router port forwarding, etc). Could you expand on that?

Comment: @rileywhite I want my clients to connect to my computer (which I want to make server) through internet. So, that my clients can consume my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% certain that I am answering the right question, but I'll give it a shot.

I believe what you are asking is: given that you are hosting a service in IIS on your personal computer, how do you allow others access to it? If my interpretation is incorrect, then please accept my apology in advance.

Note: I'm assuming IPv4 in this answer. IPv6 may be an option, but this answer would not apply.

There are two steps in the solution, and there are a few obstacles that you may or may not be able to overcome.

1. Get the client's web traffic to your public IP address.
2. Route incoming traffic to your computer.

**Step 1**

You can determine your public IP address in many ways, one of which is to ask Google: https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+my+ip

Obstacles are as follows:

1. Your IP address may change from time to time. The solution is to use a dynamic DNS service such as http://dyn.com/dns/, http://www.thatip.com/, or any of several alternatives that can be found online. These services will provide a URL that routes to your public IP, and they will provide a way to keep your public IP up-to-date so that name resoslution generally works. Keep in mind that DNS does not reliably change in realtime, however, so you should expect some downtime if and when your IP address changes.
2. Your ISP may block incoming traffic. Whether and how you can get around this is specific to your IP. Specifically, it is common for ISPs to block incoming port 20, 22, 23, 25, 80, and 443. You may be able to work around port blocking by choosing a non-standard port for your service. (This may not affect your WCF and IIS configuration as detailed in step 2.)
3. Particularly if you are using any kind of shared apartment connection, you may find that you do not have your own public IP address. If that is the case, then there is nothing you can do. If your router's WAN address (or computer's IP addres, if you're not using a router) is something in the 192.168.* or 10.* ranges, then it's time to look into server options.

**Step 2**

Once a client request has routed through the public internet to your public IP address, it needs to be routed to your computer.

The easiest, though least common these days, scenario is if your computer is directly connected to your cable/DSL modem. In this case, traffic that routes to your public IP is handled by your computer. This is the scenario where your WCF and IIS configuration needs to be listening on the actual port used by the client. For example, if your ISP is blocking port 80, then maybe you could configure your service to listen on port 34323, and that is the port that the client needs to request in the service call.

The most common scenario is that you have a router attached to your cable/DSL modem. In this case, you need to get into the administration control panel on your router and forward a port. For example, if your computer is configured to listen to port 80 for incoming service requests, then you can forward a port (for example, 34323) to port 80 on your local machine. How to forward the port differs by router. You should be able to find it by poking around or by doing an internet search.

The obstacle here is that your local IP address may change. You can overcome this by setting it to a static address outside of your router's DHCP assignment range or by setting up a DHCP reservation within your router. Either way will work. I suggest searching the internet for setting up a static IP or poking around in your router administration settings for DHCP reservations.

If you get all of your settings correct, and if there are no obstacles outside of your control, then a client on the internet can access your WCF service.

Edit:
I missed talking about local Windows firewall concerns. I could go into that, but allow me to link to this how-to guide that covers it pretty well. (Remember, a WCF service is conceptually similar to a website from a hosting standpoint, so much of this applies.) http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1774

Comment: You have answered the correct question. Thank you very much. I will give it a try and let you say if I find any problems.

Comment: Good luck. The first time you do this is a real learning experience.